# How to parameterize query sent with arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, sql-server, geoprocessing-service, security

I have been developing a geoprocessor which takes user inputs as strings to develop a dynamic sql statment sent to MSSS from an [ArcSDESQLExecute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm) class. The app will only allow for controlled input, but should someone gain access to the (secured) gp rest endpoint I need to clean the sql before sending. The ONLY property for this class is an autocommit interval, and the only methods are begin/commit/rollback transaction and execute sql(takes only one string).

Can I hack parameters into my statement with this class, or do I need to pythonically sanitize the input and concatenate it into the sql statement like a barbarian trying to gopher-whack XSS injection? Any other thoughts on keeping the db safe while using dynamic sql through this connection? Stored processes and 3rd party libraries are out.

---

CONTEXT:
I have a somewhat gnarly, non-spatial, dynamic query that's hitting an MS SQL Server db from a web app. Client is a large institution with fairly stringent networking requirements which force me to make my db connection from the data server, so I'm sending the user inputs to a script which then builds and executes the query on the server, returning a table to the client.

Because the client doesn't have much control over the network, and because the people directly managing this tool don't have any networking chops, we're sticking with a published geoprocessing service to do the lifting here. For this same reason, the libraries which my python has access to are limited to the arcpy and whatever default libraries come with ESRI's python install (numpy, json, time, w/e). I asked specifically about pymssql and mxodbc to the networking guy, who is in the know. His response wasn't a no, but close to it '~how about using arcpy.da cursors or ArcSDEExecute?' To be fair, this *is* how I learned about ArcSdeExecute. Also, cursors are not a viable option. It makes no sense to have anything other than the db handle these queries, which include nested queries, joins, and pivots. If you know a better library than arcpy that I can count on to do this task, I'm all ears.